# How to restrict a child object from calling the parent function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

How can I restrict the child object to not be able to call the parent function, when inherited?

```js
var Parent = function() {};

Parent.prototype.myF = function() {
  console.log('derp');
};

function Child() {};

//make [[prototype]] of Child be a ref to Parent.prototype
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Child.prototype.getName = function() {
  console.log('dddd')
}

var c = new Child();
c.myF();
```

I want the child class not be able to call `myF();` as possible in `Java` to make it `private`. Can I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript prototype inheritance private method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28062379/javascript-prototype-inheritance-private-method)

Answer (score 0):

**There are no private members in JavaScript.** However you can, by convention, simulate private members and mimic the intended behavior.

## Using prefixes

```js
function Child() {
    // underscore prefix
    this._var = 42;
}

var child = new Child();

console.log(child.var); // undefined
console.log(child._var); // 42
```

```js
function Child() {
    // underscore prefix
    this._prop = 42
}

Child.prototype.getProp = function() {
    return this._prop;
};

var child = new Child();

console.log(child.prop); // undefined
console.log(child._prop); // 42
console.log(child.getProp()) // 42
```

## Using closures

```js
function Child() {
    // this variable cannot be accessed 
    // directly from outside
    var prop = 42;
    
    this.getProp = function() {
        return prop;
    }
}

var child = new Child();

console.log(child.prop); // undefined
console.log(child.getProp()); // 42
```

## Private methods in future JavaScript

After [**this tc39 proposal**](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-methods) will be accepted and implemented as such, you'll be able to define private methods and fields in JavaScript.

- [**Field declarations**](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-methods#field-declarations)
- [**Private methods and fields**](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-methods#private-methods-and-fields)

---

## In your case

```js
var Parent = function() {};

Parent.prototype._myF = function() {
  console.log('derp');
};

var Child = function() {};

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Child.prototype.getName = function() {
  console.log('dddd')
}

// usage

var p = new Parent();
// notice the underscore prefix (_)
p._myF(); // "derp"

var c = new Child();
c.getName(); // "dddd"
c.myF(); // Uncaught TypeError: c.myF is not a function
```

However **you'll be able to access** the parent's function `_myF()` through the child like this: `c._myF();`. That's why, at the current state of JavaScript, if you want private members, you have to abide by the convention, that **every underscore-prefixed member should be considered as private**.

Answer (score 0):

They are no private fields in javascript yet, but currently tc39 is working on that, you have to wait for the next Ecmascript standard [private fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-fields), or you can use a transpiler that transpiles your code into some weird stuff your brain can't decipher.  But this might solve your problem, you have to check the constructor property, if it is the parent or the child,

```
function Parent() {};

Parent.prototype.doThis = function() {
    if ( this.constructor.name != "Parent" )
        throw new Error("You are not allowed to call this method");
    console.log("derp");
};

function Child() {};

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

Child.prototype.getName = function() {
    console.log("ddd");
};

let p = new Parent();
let c = new Child();


console.log(p.doThis());
console.log(c.getName());
console.log(c.doThis());
```